# homebrew doctor: gettext found

Tags: gettext, homebrew

I try to get homebrew running in order to install some unix tools on may mac and have trouble getting started. I already removed fink and macports und installed homebrew.

(I'm running Snow Leopard 10.6.8 and have XCode 3.2.6 installed.)

When checking whether my system is ready to go the "brew doctor" command reports several errors:
The first is:

```
Warning: gettext was detected in your PREFIX.
The gettext provided by Homebrew is "keg-only", meaning it does not
get linked into your PREFIX by default.

If you `brew link gettext` then a large number of brews that don't
otherwise have a `depends_on 'gettext'` will pick up gettext anyway
during the `./configure` step.

If you have a non-Homebrew provided gettext, other problems will happen
especially if it wasn't compiled with the proper architectures.
```

What shall I do about this? Or how can I remove this?
Thanks in advance
cheers

Answer (score 4):

In /usr/local/Library/Homebrew/cmd/doctor.rb I found:

```
def check_for_gettext
  if %w[lib/libgettextlib.dylib
        lib/libintl.dylib
        include/libintl.h ].any? { |f| File.exist? "#{HOMEBREW_PREFIX}/#{f}" }
```

While I personally deleted everything get text and libintl from under /usr/local, it's probably sufficient to rename libgettextlib.dylib, libintl.dylib and libintl.h to something else (e.g. postfix with -pre-homebrew).